# Collection list of un-real numbers

Tags: real-numbers

I am sorry if this question is off-topic here. This is not really a question, but more a request to provide examples of un-real numbers.

So far I know only one example that I will put in the list below.

However, to justify this post, I will yet ask this: Would it be correct to say that an un-real number is not a number at all, but rather some kind of concept of a phenomenon that simply doesn't exist in the objective reality?

---

List of examples of un-real numbers:

1. Any square root of any negative number;
2. ?

Comment: What is an unreal number?

Comment: @JohnDouma - That is a number that doesn't belong to real numbers.

Comment: The ratio of the hypotenuse to the leg is a real number. Irrational numbers are still real numbers.

Comment: @soupless - Oops! Sorry. I got confused. I will delete it from the list. Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494854/what-is-a-number, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865409/what-exactly-is-a-number/865467, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671148/how-can-we-recognize-if-something-is-a-number, etc.

Comment: Also, maybe you want surreal numbers?

Comment: @soupless - What is surreal numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ultimately just comes down to playing with definitions. What exactly do you mean by a number? If you mean a member of ${\mathbb{C}}$, then by an "un-real" number, assuming you mean a number that is not strictly real, that is precisely the set ${\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}}$. Otherwise, without a precise definition of what exactly you are talking about, the question is ill-posed.

Comment: Why answer ill-posed questions? The normal procedure at MSE is to ask for a clarification and if none is forthcoming, then vote to close.

Comment: I am sorry. I thought there was a precise definition of unreal number in math.

Comment: @MoisheKohan because I think giving an answer that the question is ill-posed is still a valuable answer, especially because questions of this sort usually imply there is some notion of a number outside of an abstract definition depending on the current context. It's essentially just word-play, and I think any opportunity to point out such word-play is definitely one worth taking

Comment: @brilliant no need to be sorry, now you know!

Comment: @brilliant maybe you would be interested in looking at Quaternions, though, as these are closely related to complex numbers

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose: Are you aware of [EOQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)? If not, please, read closely.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose - I'll look at Quaternions. Thank you.

Comment: This should be a comment, as it does not answer the question.  As @MoisheKohan points out succinctly, seek clarification, give feedback/suggestions for clarification, in comments below a question.  Only answer if and when you fully understand the question.