# Why does Wolfram Alpha say that $\infty^\infty$ results in "complex infinity"?

Tags: exponentiation, infinity, wolfram-alpha

When entered into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=infinity%5Einfinity), $\infty^\infty$ results in [complex infinity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexInfinity.html).

Why is $\infty^\infty=\tilde\infty$?

Comment: It isn't. $\infty^\infty$ is meaningless. Wolfram Alpha isn't truth, and you'd have to ask one of the programmers why their software chooses to respond that.

Comment: try $\frac{1}{0}$, you will get the same answer

Comment: Just an advice: dont trust wolfram-alpha or any other mathematical software.

Comment: There may be some **computational purposes** behind.  For example, Series[(1+1/n)^n,{n,infinity,2}] gives $$e-\frac{e}{2n}+O\left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)$$

Comment: @Canardini That makes sense on the Riemann sphere, though.

Comment: To be honest, A video for the explanation could be much more wise to answer this beautiful mathematics question. This isn't just about concepts but about the mental clarity on needs to have when we are talking Mathematics on Stack Exchange.I found this video from VSAUCE (youtube channel) that has dedicated a hearty effort on this ver basic question. Finding something for you is always a pleasure. But when it's precise?
Thats when I feel 'accomplished'. The link is ~ https://youtu.be/SrU9YDoXE88

Comment: Specifically, you shouldn't trust any software when asking about $\infty$, since it will usually cut it short to some finite number and/or do weird things with it.  Indeed, $\infty$ isn't a number to begin with.

Comment: I'm glad those with understanding answered this question, when so many were quick to say it was meaningless and an error in software.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

WA's `ComplexInfinity` is the same as Mathematica's: it represents a complex "number" which has infinite magnitude but unknown or nonexistent phase. One can use `DirectedInfinity` to specify the phase of an infinite quantity, if it approaches infinity in a certain direction. The standard `Infinity` is the special case of phase 0. Note that `Infinity` is different from `Indeterminate` (which would be the output of e.g. `0/0`).

Some elucidating examples:

- `0/0` returns `Indeterminate`, since (for instance) the limit may be approached as $\frac{1/n}{1/n}$ or $\frac{2/n}{1/n}$, resulting in two different real numbers.
- `1/0` returns `ComplexInfinity`, since (for instance) the limit may be approached as $\frac{1}{-1/n}$ or as $\frac{1}{1/n}$, but every possible way of approaching the limit gives an infinite answer.
- `Abs[1/0]` returns `Infinity`, since the limit is guaranteed to be infinite and approached along the real line in the positive direction.

---

In your particular example, you get `ComplexInfinity` because the infinite limit may be approached as (e.g.) $n^n$ or as $n^{n+i}$.

Comment: Glad to see this as an answer. Well addresses Mathematica's reasoning here, with well drawn out examples. +1.

Comment: I doubt $(-n)^n$ is a valid way to do the limit — presumably WA interprets the "infinity" in the question to be a directed infinity, of argument/phase zero (that is, "positive infinity"). However, $n^{n+i}$ would work.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks, that's a much better example.

Comment: Note that `Abs[1/0]` is evaluated to `Abs[ComplexInfinity]`, only then this result becomes `Infinity`. It's not something for which Mathematica computes the whole expression as a limit.

Comment: 0/0, outside of a limit, is not indeterminate: it is simply undefined. (Although we might say the lack of a definition is motivated by no consistent limits in this regard.) Indeed, Wolfram Alpha returns "undefined",  not "indeterminate", in this case. But then it appends some indeterminate limits in case you want to investigate those, which likely furthers the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, this answer along with Brevan Ellefsen's answer explain it very clearly! If I could, I would accept both as the answer. I have learned a lot through both the answers and comments on this question, and this discussion is an exemplary example of the awesome culture of the Math Stack Exchange!

Comment: @Idempotence thank you for such a kind comment. A compliment like that is always better than the reputation from accepting or upvoting in my book! I hope you find the rest of your time on this site equally enjoyable, and if you really enjoy the site, I invite you to try answering questions sometime! I love answering questions on this site for much the same reason you enjoyed the answers you got - the supportive community and the learning I do along the way. I imagine I often end up learning a whole lot more from the posts I answer than the OP does!

Answer (score 13):

*TLDR: $\infty$ is not a number, and thus $\infty^\infty$ is meaningless, and Wolfram Alpha is using $\tilde\infty$ to represent something I like to to think of in the sense of "[one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension)", a topological concept*

A.) The symbol $\infty$ is not a number in its own right. It can represent a lot of things, and many different objects can be "infinitely large". Just think of something infinite as something not finite and you are generally off to a good start.

B.) If infinity is not a number, we can't do arithmetic on it that makes sense in all context, and so we most definitely can't exponetiate it meaningfully without some fundamentals first. For example,

1. there are some infinite things where arithmetic is defined (in some
   sense - check out [ordinal
   numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number)),
2. There are
   some things where basic arithmetic does nothing (i.e.
   $\infty+1=\infty$)
3. There are some infinite thing where you most
   definitely cannot do arithmetic in the way you are used to (take,
   for example, the limit concept of infinity from a basic Calculus
   class)

C) Wolfram Alpha appears to represent a lot of things as $\tilde\infty$ that are ill-defined according to the real-number system you are used to - for example, according to Wolfram Alpha, $\frac{1}{0}=\tilde\infty$, whereas I would say that $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined. You could stretch this to say that $\frac{1}{0} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1x = \pm\infty$ in the extended-real number system, but this is starting to push things. To really understand what Wolfram Alpha is doing you must first understand the one-point compactification of $\Bbb C$. See my note at the bottom for links and more details.

**Notes:**

1. It has been pointed out in the comments that I ought to mention that
   Mathematica/WA use $\tilde\infty$ to represent an infinite magnitude
   number with no defined phase. This seemed more software dependent,
   though I get where the the commentator is coming from. I chose to
   focus on the real number system the OP is likely accustomed to, and
   focus on the concept of $\infty^\infty$ itself, not the software's
   interpretation.
2. $\tilde\infty$ *does* have meaning in some
       sense - see for example, this Wikipedia page on "[one-point
       compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension)". Just imagine the complex plane as a big sheet where we take the edges and pull them all into one point and call it $\infty$. For more information look at the page on the [Riemann Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere). Similarly, $\infty$ can have a defined meaning in certain contexts outside of the scope of this question - see, for example, the Wikipedia page on the [Real Projective Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_line). In these contexts, one *could* perhaps consider $\infty$ a number. For more on this, see the Wikipedia page ["Projectively Extended Real Line"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line).

Comment: Quibble: It's not a _real_ number. What about the point of $RP^1$ with coordinates $(0,1)$ ?

Comment: The points of $\mathbb RP^1$ are not numbers. @Spencer

Comment: @PatrickStevens I agree with you completely.... I edited my post to reflect this with a note at the end. I attempted to more explain the concept of $\infty^\infty$ and what it could mean instead of what $\tilde\infty$ means according to Mathematica... feel free to post an answer tackling that part of the question!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh really? One of the answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494854/what-is-a-number  contradicts this. We could argue at length about what a number is, but it would be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Spencer your point is perhaps valid, if far beyond the scope here... I chose to barely mention the complex plane, let alone try to pin down the definition of a number.

Comment: I am _sure_ $\tilde\infty$ refers to the extra point in the one-point compactification of $\Bbb C$ (that is, the Riemann sphere).

Comment: I appear to have been downvoted. While I don't much care about the downvote itself, I would be glad to edit the post in any way to appease any issues found in it that prompted the downvote.

Comment: @Spencer Check out this [answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/865467/7933), with 44 votes. "Number" is a very loosely defined term, of course - there is no rigorous meaning of the term. For the purposes here, no, the elements of $\mathbb RP^1$ are not "numbers," any more than the elements of $\mathbb RP^3$ are numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The necessity of saying "for the purposes here" is exactly the point of my "quibble" -- Brevan's answer (which has my upvote) would be better if it contained that phrase, or some variant of it.

Comment: @Spencer hmm. Regardless of how we want to define the term "number", I'm not sure it would be super enlightening to say that "infinity is not a number, except when we compactify $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ or do some similar stuff". While I agree there are contexts this makes sense, I was careful to not even mention the Riemann Sphere until the notes at the bottom... I would rather say a slightly incorrect statement than hopelessly confuse the OP. I can add a phrase "for the purposes here" if you think it would help though/

Comment: @Spencer I added a bit to my second note. Does this suffice? Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry but, what means TLDR? I searched in google the meaning of this acronym but google says it is for "too long, didnt read" what dont seem the case for your use.

Comment: @Masacroso that's absolutely what I meant in this case. TLDR is used in forums at the top of posts to give a brief description of the post... Perhaps the reader is in a hurry and so they can't read the whole post because it's too long. In that case the reader would say the post is *too long* so they *didn't read* it all.

Comment: @Masacroso  in this case specifically it wasn't "too long" as much as is possibly above the OP's reading level at this point, but since the post was relatively long anyway I abused notation a bit.

Answer (score 7):

An interpretation in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ of $\infty^\infty$ is *via* limits. For example $$\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)^{\frac{1}{|z|}}\underbrace{=}_{\text{symbolic equality}}\infty^\infty=\infty.$$ *Note.* $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ don't belong to $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell: When $x$ and $y$ approach positive infinity, Wolfram Alpha assumes they may do so through the complex plane, as long as the arguments (angles) of $x$ and $y$ approach zero.

The argument of $x^{x+i}$ does not converge to any value as $x\to\infty$, even though the arguments of $x$ and $x+i$ go to zero. (This is because the argument is $\ln x$.) Thus, Wolfram Alpha responds with complex infinity (unknown argument) rather than positive infinity.